# AWS Custom AMI - how to see what it has set within?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to check the existing custom AMI and what it has set within it without launching it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a copy of a disk.

It typically contains the Operating System (if it was created from a boot disk), together with any applications and data that have been stored on the disk.

Any AMIs supplied by AWS or other companies will normally list what is installed (eg which version operating system, which applications).

If you have created an AMI from your own Amazon EC2 instance, then only *you* will know what is on the AMI.